# Скрипт для базы

Tags: java, база-данных, spring

Приложение на spring. База postgres. Я хранил в таблице дату в String.

Если я захочу изменить тип этого поля на LocalDate, то он выдаст ошибку, что не ожидает такой тип в уже имеющихся записях. И что делать в таких случаях? Удалять базу и заново заполнять?

Comment: Ну в качестве костыльного решения могу предложить создать временную таблицу с теми же полями, как и оригинальная, после чего через select пихнуть в нее все то, что уже есть в оригинальной таблице. Далее очистите оригинальную таблицу, измените тип столбца и заселектите все записи обратно из временной таблицы в измененную оригинальную, кастанув нужный вам столбец в LocalDate.

Comment: Alter table. Не?

Comment: @Egettl это вероятно сработает... хоть и займёт время =)

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець у меня стоит в пропертях опция spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true, что при компилящии изменяет схему, если были внесены изменения. Поэтому, видимо и возникает ошибка, о которой я писал. Тип изменился, а содержимое типа String. Меня таки и интересует способ программно изменить базу. Чтобы описать поведение, типа: приведи String к типу LocaleDate или если не можешь, то запиши пустую строку. Может есть какая-то технология